# Error message when updating a multi-valued field in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint-2010

I am using Access 2010, and Sharepoint 2010 which is why I have the multi-valued field. I have looked through this website and through other articles and have found that I need to add .value onto the end of the multi-valued field to make it work. I have tried this but no matter what I do I continue to get the error message 'An Insert Into query cannot contain a multi-valued field'

This is the code I am using, can anyone see what I am missing?

```
INSERT INTO [Table2] ( ID, [Hiring Manager], [Req ID], Status.value, LTM, [Req Link], Attachments )
    SELECT [Table1].test, [Table1].[Hiring Manager], [Table1].[Req ID],
           [Table1].[Status].value, [Table1].LTM, [Table1].[Req Link], 
           [Table1].Attachments 
    FROM [Table1];
```

I know it is probably something simple but I have been staring at this for so long that I believe a fresh pair of eyes will be able to spot the issue.

To provide a little more detail, the tables contain requests for internal job openings. The multi-valued field can either be approved, rejected or on hold. Table 2 are all new requests and table1 are existing requests, so I need to move all of table2 into table1.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify the question.

Comment: What is your actual BE? Access? SharePoint Lists? SQL Azure? SQL Server? The last two don't support Access' multi-Valued fields. If SharePoint list, you'll need to do some research according to the version of SharePoint you are using.

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2010 list that is linked to a table within access

Comment: Isn't the error message pretty self explanatory?  Also why use the multi-valued field.. they always end up causing more problems then they are worth. Split your data into fields and problem solved. Additionally, why have two tables when just one will do the job?